# how to show warning\error for int to long value

Tags: c#, .net

Maybe somebody will help me or point to the way.
If I create a controller and service and pass requestId value from controller to service.

```
    //controller
    [HttpDelete]
    public IActionResult Delete([FromRoute]int requestId)
    {
        requestApiService.Delete(requestId);

        return NoContentResult();
    }

    //service
    public void Delete(long requestId, int platformClientId)
    {
        //some logic here
    }
```

I want to get error or warning in Visual Studio, because i send int value from controller to long value in service.
I understand that this code is ok, but i want to get some warning if i will have this situation in code.
May be somebody knows how to do this.
Thanks!

**Edit:**
I apologize but looks like my code is confusion you. I want to get this warning is because of it simple to refactoring the code. E.g. i have API layer (with controllers), ApiService, AppService, Data(Repository) layers.

```
//controller
[HttpDelete("{orderId:int}")]
public IActionResult Delete([FromRoute] int orderId)
{
    incomingOrderApiService.Delete(orderId);
    return NoContentResult();
}

// api service layer
public void Delete(int orderId)
{
   //call app service layer
   incomingOrderAppService.Delete(orderId);
}

//app service layer
public void Delete(int orderId)
{
    var order = genericRepository.Get<IncomingOrderEntity>(orderId);
    if (order != null)
    {
        genericRepository.SoftDelete(order);
    }
}

//entity for Fluent Nhibernate mapping
public class IncomingOrderEntity : DomainEntity, IAuditableEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So, if i change in IncomingOrderEntity Id property from int to long my code will compile successfully, but i want to get warnings from VS to find and change int to long everywhere in code. E.g. change in Entity -> fix at the app service layer -> fix at the api service layer -> fix at the controller layer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to error or warn this?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (requestId > someValue) throw new ArgumentException("Request Id is greater than expected maximum.", nameof(requestId));`?

Answer (score 0):

I question the use case of throwing an error on a widening cast. For a narrowing cast it makes sense, but not really here because all ints are valid longs. But we can do a workaround with an overload that accepts integers. When the compiler is looking for Delete, it can use the `long` version because an implicit cast exists. When we add a new Delete that takes ints this one becomes a closer match because the type is exact

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete([FromRoute]int requestId)
{
    requestApiService.Delete(requestId);

    return NoContentResult();
}

//service
public void Delete(long requestId, int platformClientId)
{
    //some logic here
}

//service
public void Delete(int requestId, int platformClientId)
{
   throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: The service version of `Delete` that throws the exception will always be run.

Comment: Yeah there's definitely ambiguity around why you would want to do something like this in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an overload that takes in an `integer`, you can mark it as `Obsolete`, which will generate a compiler warning. You can also add a custom `#warning` tag inside the method:

```
[Obsolete("Please use the overload that takes a long")]
public static void Delete(int requestId, int platformClientId)
{
    #warning We don't like Int32 around here.

    // Call the correct method anyway?
    Delete((long) requestId, platformClientId);
}
```

Now, when we call each of these methods, the first method (with the integer) gets underlined and the intellisense says, `"'Program.Delete(int, int)' is obsolete: 'Please use the overload that takes a long'"`. Additionally, when we build the project, there will be two warnings:

```
CS1030 #warning: 'We don't like Int32 around here.'
CS0612 'Program.Delete(int, int)' is obsolete: 'Please use the overload that takes a long'
```

[image]